# Comment on the accentual structure of the following word: overvalue

Tags: accent, stress

I tried to describe the stress pattern of the word **overvalue**,  but the only thing that I found is that it has the secondary stress. How to describe it fully?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pronunciation dictionary such the *Longman Pronunciation dictionary* will give you the most up to date pronunciation for British English (RP) and the pronunciation for Gen AM so as to allow you to compare. However, in order to specialize in American pronunciation I advise that you use some other dictionary, that is one that treats specifically the subject of American pronunciation; not having studied the subject myself, I can't recommend any.

This is LPD's symbols (essentially IPA, with rare changes and additions)

ˌəʊv ɘ 'væl ju: (RP)

oʊv r 'væl ju: (General American)

- This is an ˌoverˌvalued 'estimate.
- They ˌoverˌvalued that 'limit.

Comment: There might be contexts (with contrastive stress) where the first syllable takes the primary accent and the third syllable takes a secondary accent: "He tends rather to overvalue the older employees than to undervalue them."

Comment: @BrianDonovan Very true, there is not often a context for it, but it is a useful and well established possibility, useful, for example, in corrective statements.